# How to listen for AffectsParentArrange events when you're not the parent

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

There is an attribute "AffectsParentArrange" that implicitly invalidates the parent's layout - but I want to attach an event handler to the "event" triggered by that attribute.

When a child property with the attribute changes, the parent's arrangement is invalidated.

I have a custom control (which is not the immediate parent) that needs to receive an event.

Does anyone know of an event that can be used here?

Do I need to provide a custom parent that overrides a method and fires an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just calls `InvalidateArrange()` on the parent when the property change.  This causes WPF to later call `Arrange()` on the parent.  Neither of these calls has any way to intercept it (without using *really* sneaky techniques like patching IL code or attaching a debugger to the process).

This means that the only ways to write managed code that can detect the `InvalidateArrange()` is to create a custom parent which overrides the `ArrangeOverride` method, or tap into some behavior of the `Arrange` method for the particular control in question - for example if the parent is a `Panel` you could add an extra invisible child just to receive `Arrange()` calls from its parent.

**Update** When you get the Arrange() callback you cannot detect why InvalidateArrange() was called on the parent, but you can detect whether the property with the `AffectsParentArrange` flag has changed or not by saving the old value of the property in each `Arrange` call and comparing it to the previously saved value.  This can be extended to multiple properties using a loop, a Dictionary, and either a list of properties or a call to `GetLocalValueEnumerator()`.

Comment: Problem is that ArrangeOverride can't differentiate between top-down and bottom-up.  Sending an event from there would send every time the arrangement is invalidated from any source.  Unfortunately, one of the side-effects of my event handler is to cause the control to be rearranged.

Comment: No problem.  I've added the solution to this to my answer.